# Android Studio 3 Beta 2 ExecutionException AaptException AAPT2 link failed

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Im using MAC and Im getting this error when I try to run my app.

```
Error:(1419, 5) style attribute 'attr/metaButtonBarStyle (aka com.app:attr/metaButtonBarStyle)' not found
Error:(1419, 5) style attribute 'attr/metaButtonBarButtonStyle (aka com.app:attr/metaButtonBarButtonStyle)' not found
Error:/Users/me/appandroid/App/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1747 style attribute 'attr/metaButtonBarStyle (aka com.app:attr/metaButtonBarStyle)' not found
Error:failed linking references
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Dont work cleaning, rebuilding, restarting, changing utf language, etc.

Any idea?

Comment: I think that the problem is for use different versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1 in the project

Comment: got your solution ?

Comment: Yes, check your dependencies in gradle @PrakhaRaM

Comment: @PabloCegarra what does it means ?

Comment: @user2396640 all your android dependencies must be the same version, you cant have 26.0.1 and 26.0.2 at the same time